# Best flooring option for a home gym?

Tags: gym, home-exercise

I'm turning an unused bedroom into a dedicated home gym. Nothing fancy, a couple of bikes plus a small multigym and/or weights.

Currently there is an old, stained carpet on top of period (uneven creaky) wooden floorboards. I had favoured the idea to toss the carpet and paint the boards but try might take too much work.

I don't really want to be sweating on a new carpet so what is recommended for flooring?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that horsestalls use half inch thick 6 by 4 foot mats that you can have delivered by any horse products business.  They are heavy.  It takes two people to move one (or one very young strong person). I bought some of these for a basement gym once.  It seems like a very challenging task to set them up, but it wasn't really so bad.

See for [example](https://www.farmstore.com/product/rb-rubber-34-in-rubber-stall-mat-4-x-8-ft/),

Comment: I like this out of the (horse) box thinking but can you clarify what these are made from? Any idea on product name since I know nothing about horses. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mr.Boy  I added a link to  my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used flooring from https://www.gym-flooring.com/collections/gym-mats

I opted for the 11mm but I'm getting on a bit and can't lift as much as I used to. Rated up to 110kg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).